# Is there a way to set a relative top percentage for div boxes in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, parallax

I wanted to create a box with content (images + text) inside with parallax background. I improvised my box from this login page tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HV7DtH3J2PU and ended up with this:

```
.box{
width: 700px;
padding: 40px;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
background: #191919;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 12px;}
```

the problem is, when the content exceeds a certain amount, which is irregular, the box goes through the top. the original code used the`top: 50%` to deal with this, but since every page has different content, currently i have to manually set the percentages. is there a way to fix this?

edit: and for the parallax, i just added

```
body {
margin-left : 0px;
padding : 0px;
color: white;
width: 100%;
background-image : url(../pg/images/pg_home_background.png);
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

edit 2: here is the html code

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="box">
<h4>title</h4>
<p>....some long text and content...</p>
<img src="image.png" width ="854", height ="480">
<p>....some long text and content...</p>
<img src="image.png" width ="854", height ="480">
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Post HTML to help us help you. Minimal, Reproducible Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @ikiK i added the html code to the question. sorry for the inconvenience